Cannot align bottom border of an input and a textarea inside a div table
I try to align the bottom border of an input element and a textarea so that both bottom borders of the input and the textarea are exacty aligned and on the same line. Both the input element and the textarea are inside a table. I build my table with divs (display: {table, table-row-groupe, table-row and table-cell}. So far, I have not been able to solve the problem and when I view the page in Firefox and Microsoft Edge, the bottom borders which I indicated with white color (on a black background) are not horizontally aligned.
Therefore I'm going to provide here a working test case, so that you might be able to reproduce easily and instantly my problem.
Note : For this test case to work, both CSS and HTML file must be in the same directory.


.DivTab {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.DivTabBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.DivTabRow {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.DivTabCell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: start;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  color: #cfd0ce;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.KeyClass {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid #ffffff 1px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

.ValueClass {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid #ffffff 1px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  resize: none;
  width: 95%;
  font-family: Consolas;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alignment example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Input and Textarea align example">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color: #000000;">
  <div style="width: 60%;">
    <div class="DivTab">
      <div class="DivTabBody">
        <div class="DivTabRow">
          <div class="DivTabCell" style="width: 30%;">
            <input id="paramKey" type="text" class="KeyClass">
          </div>
          <div class="DivTabCell" style="width: 70%;">
            <textarea id="paramValue" rows="1" spellcheck="false" class="ValueClass"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



Could you kindly indicate, where is my mistake and how can I make these two bottom borders aligned?
Thanks in advance.

Ok, I solved the problem. The main issue was, that inside ValueClass
Instead of
margin-left: 5px;

I had to write:
margin: 0px;
margin-left: 5px;

Without doing so, apparently there are some default values (which are unknown to me) for other margins.
I also added text-align: bottom; in the two cells containing the input and the textarea element.
I also added the following lines to the CSS (based on Waqas's response)
box-sizing: border-box;
line-height: 1.2;
vertical-align: bottom;

So for those who might have encountered the same problem, here is the new working version:
HTML file (test.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alignment example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Input and Textarea align example">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #000000;">

<div style="width: 60%;">
    <div class="DivTab">
        <div class="DivTabBody">
            <div class="DivTabRow">
                <div class="DivTabCell" style="width: 30%; vertical-align: bottom;">
                    <input id="paramKey" type="text" class="KeyClass">
                </div>
                <div class="DivTabCell" style="width: 70%; vertical-align: bottom;">
                    <textarea id="paramValue" rows="1" 
                        spellcheck="false" class="ValueClass"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

The CSS file (styles.css):
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.DivTab {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.DivTabBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}

.DivTabRow {
    display: table-row;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.DivTabCell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: start;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    color:  #cfd0ce;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.KeyClass {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid #ffffff 1px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Consolas;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1.2;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.ValueClass {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid #ffffff 1px;
    resize: none;
    width: 95%;
    font-family: Consolas;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1.2;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

I tested on Firefox (version: 129.0.1 - 64 Bit) and Microsoft Edge (version: 127.0.2651.98 - 64 Bit) and it worked on both browsers.

The issue with the alignment of bottom border of the input and textarea element
use box-sizing: border-box in these classes .KeyClass, .ValueClass and also use vertical-align: middle; in class .DivTabCell
Here is working example on my side: 
test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alignment example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Input and Textarea align example">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color: #000000;">
    <div style="width: 60%;">
        <div class="DivTab">
            <div class="DivTabBody">
                <div class="DivTabRow">
                    <div class="DivTabCell" style="width: 30%;">
                        <input id="paramKey" type="text" class="KeyClass">
                    </div>
                    <div class="DivTabCell" style="width: 70%;">
                        <textarea id="paramValue" rows="1" spellcheck="false" class="ValueClass"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

styles.css
.DivTab {
       display: table;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       color: #ffffff;
       background-color: #000000;
    }
    
   .DivTabBody {
       display: table-row-group;
    }
    
    .DivTabRow {
       display: table-row;
       background-color: #000000;
     }
    
     .DivTabCell {
        display: table-cell;
        /* add changes */
        vertical-align: middle; 
        text-align: start;
        padding: 0;
        color: #cfd0ce;
        background-color: #000000;
     }
    
    .KeyClass,
    .ValueClass {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: solid #ffffff 1px;
        font-family: Consolas;
        /* changes */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        line-height: 1.5;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    
    .KeyClass {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .ValueClass {
        margin-left: 5px;
        resize: none;
        width: calc(100% - 5px);
        overflow-y: hidden;
        height: 22px;
    }

This is working on my side hopefully that's works for you, Thanks.

Thank you for your time and for your help.

Thanks we always here to help each other.

If your requirement is to align elements side by side then using flex will be much better option. Talking about issue if you inspect the textarea then you will observe that it is floating to top side of its parent div and that is causing issue of input and textarea not aligning horizontally to fix that just add display: flex; next to width: 70%;
But if you want to make your code more flexible then add display: flex to DivTabRow & DivTabCell. You can ignore using display: table-cell; if you don't have specific need.
That's all. Below is working example.


body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.DivTab {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.DivTabBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}

.DivTabRow {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.DivTabCell {
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: start;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    color:  #cfd0ce;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.KeyClass {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid #ffffff 1px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Consolas;
}

.ValueClass {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid #ffffff 1px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    resize: none;
    width: 95%;
    font-family: Consolas;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
<div style="width: 60%;">
    <div class="DivTab">
        <div class="DivTabBody">
            <div class="DivTabRow">
                <div class="DivTabCell" style="width: 30%;">
                    <input id="paramKey" type="text" class="KeyClass">
                </div>
                <div class="DivTabCell" style="width: 70%;">
                    <textarea id="paramValue" rows="1" 
                        spellcheck="false" class="ValueClass"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Thank you for your help. Your solution seems to work in Microsoft Edge but not in Firefox which if you look, you will notice that the border bottom of the textarea is still a bit higher. The fact that I have table-cell is a requirement. As I said these elements are inside tables (simulated with divs) and If I'm not wrong, display:flex and table concept don't go together (at least not with table-cell)
